# Discord Bot Won't Play YouTube Video

Tags: python, discord

(This is for a discord bot btw, my code runs perfectly, the bot can join the voice channel, leave, but when I request for it to play something, that is where the problem comes in.)
I am getting an error that does not tell me where in my code the error is.
The error I am getting is [NULL @ 0x5596fd23d8e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '5'
5: Invalid argument

Here is the part of the code I believe the error is in.

```
@commands.command()
async def disconnect(self,ctx):
  await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect_streamed 1'
    '-reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,
      **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I saw something about the output being wrong on another thread but I did not understand how to fix the output.

Comment: try sending the url to a channel, and opening it on your own, it should open a voice only link. Get better error message. This can be done, if you remove your error handler, and instead let the bot crash, displaying the full traceback message

Comment: This is an ffmpeg error that happens when you're passing the arguments to it incorrectly. You need to be sending a valid list of arguments to ffmpeg. It's interpreting the `5` in `-reconnect_delay_max 5` as the input file name for whatever reason. I notice you don't have dashes before a few arguments, like `before_options`, but you do have dashes on others. This inconsistency leads me to believe that the dashes are likely related to the problem.

Comment: try joining the `'-reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'` into one, as I have shown here

Comment: YAY it works now thank you so much all of you, all of your comments fixed it. :)